# Call a function after login fails or success laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to call a custom function when the user success in login and another when fails but i can't find the solution, i use laravel 5.3 and make:auth method.

I have the LoginController but is almost emtpy.

The route for login post:

```
Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
```

I have a helper function called `flash('The messaje')` that sends an jquery alert on the view, i use in controllers and works fine, but i don't know where put this code to show an alert if the auth login fails and success.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As by default LoginController uses `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, all you need to is to write custom methods `sendLoginResponse` and `sendFailedLoginResponse`. You can of reuse trait methods and to add only custom mode you want to execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! Where can i read it? I read all the documentation and i didn't found that.

Comment: @RobertoParma Sometimes you need to look at source code :)

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, where is that file? One last question, and if for example i want to send a message to logout method to? Thanks a lot Marcin!